# How to make formula between 2 datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How to connect two data grid views so that their data is updated automatically. E.g. When coloumb1 in DataGridView1 increases then Coloumb2 in DatagridView2.

Comment: Help you what? Make a program for you? Its is very wide question. Please  [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) what kind of questions we expecting here.

Comment: you do not want to make formula  between datagridviews that is c# not excel ... ,what you want is to calculate/manipulate/add/remove your objects which are shown in your DGViews

Comment: between do we talk about a WPF,Winforms or ASP Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing my idea to implement a solution where changing a value in a cell updates another value

First, Make a class like CellRelation - its purpose is to establish a relation between 2 Grid cells.

```
  class CellRelation
  {
     DataGridCell SourceCell;
     DataGridCell DestinationCell;
     Func<DataGridCell, DataGridCell, decimal> Formula;      

  }
```

Secondly, Initialization

1. Populate your Grids as you currently do
2. For all the grid cells where you wish to have a formula, create an instance of CellRelation & add it do a collection - CellRelations
3. When you create an instance of CellRelation -> provide it with source cell that, destination cell and a delegate.

for example in your case if you would like to calculate remaining inventory -

Source Cell will be Sold Inventry, destination cell will be remainig inventory cell.

Formula (delegate): I have thought of this delegate to expect 2 grid cells as inputs and give the result as decimal.

the the input grid cells will be "TotalInventoryCell" & "SoldInvenoryCell" 
and this delegate will be a funcition to subtract the values of the given cells. The return of the delegate will be a decimal value that you can use to update the remainig inventory cell

Thirdly, the event of updating a cell in grid one.

1. When the value of the cell changes in the grid, handle the appropriate event. On this event handler, traverse the collection – CellRelations, to find if there is a dependent cell whose value needs to be updated as per the formula          entered.
2. If you find an entry for the cell getting updated, execute the delegate(formula) and use the decimal value returned by the delegate(formula) to update the destination Cell’s value

Incase you think some part is unclear please let me know, I'll try to provide a sample

---

Working Sample

I made a short working sample (without dataset) to demonstrate my approach. 
I made a single datagridview with one row & 3 columns - Total, Sold & Remaining

So every time a change is made to Sold cell, the remaining item gets update.

I made it with single grid but the same can be extended for 2 grids also. 
It has a lot of scope for improvement, especially the expression part, ideally it should be able to evaluate an expression tree.

```
class CellRelation
{
    public DataGridViewCell SourceCell;
    public DataGridViewCell DestinationCell;
    public CellFormula Formula;
}

class CellFormula
{
    public Func<DataGridViewCell, DataGridViewCell, decimal> Operator;
    public DataGridViewCell Operand1;
    public DataGridViewCell Operand2;
    public decimal Evaluate()
    {
        return Operator(Operand1, Operand2);
    }
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    List<CellRelation> cellRelations = new List<CellRelation>();


    private void Initialise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var soldCell = this.dataGridView1[1, 0];
        var remainingCell = this.dataGridView1[2, 0];
        var totalCell = this.dataGridView1[0, 0];

        // datagid values --- In your case this is from a dataset
        totalCell.Value = 10;
        soldCell.Value = 0;
        remainingCell.Value = 10;


        // initialise the relation / formula
        CellRelation relation = new CellRelation();
        relation.SourceCell = soldCell;
        relation.DestinationCell = remainingCell; // thats the dependent cell
        relation.Formula = new CellFormula();

        // here is a sample of subtraction formula :  Subtracting Sold items for total items
        relation.Formula.Operator = new Func<DataGridViewCell, DataGridViewCell, decimal>((p, v) => { return ((decimal.Parse(p.Value.ToString()))) - ((decimal.Parse(v.Value.ToString()))); });
        relation.Formula.Operand1 = totalCell;
        relation.Formula.Operand2 = soldCell;

        cellRelations.Add(relation);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //look up if there is an destination cell for the cell being updated 
        var cellReln = cellRelations.FirstOrDefault(item => item.SourceCell.RowIndex == e.RowIndex && item.SourceCell.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex);
        if (cellReln != null)
        {
            cellReln.DestinationCell.Value = cellReln.Formula.Evaluate();
        }
    }
```

}

Edit : Please note - the approach I have suggested is with CellRelation & CellFormula has properties with type DataGridViewCell. Therefore its tightly bound to the UI technology (winform in this case). 
Ideally such a solution should be UI technology independent.  Incase you need a sample where this sits in a separate business layer, do write me a comment.

Comment: do u need something like an excel ? so say you change a value in one cell  and a formula gets executed and the result is seen in destination cell ?

Comment: yes, i think i understand your point.. so you have 2 grids, the datasource is a common dataset for both the grid & now you need some sort of event mechanism that whenever you change one value,  the other one gets updated.  Correct so far ?

Comment: To be more precise, are looking for such a wiring in the code ?  - Grid one makes a change to dataset -> a formula gets executed -> the result of the formula updates another value of the dataset -> Grid 2 (linked to this value of dataset) gets updated since its datasource has changed

Comment: alright I'll give you a idea of what comes to my mind... please give me few minutes

Comment: hahah... u r very kind

Comment: well what comes to my mind is not an out of box solution that you can look up at google but an approach & design to implement something like an excel -> where when a cell is changed, the destination cell gets updated as per a formula... I write it & incase my write up is not too clear, I'll implement a sample tomorrow evening. Would that be fine ?

Comment: Excel spread sheet in C#,,, This may give some cleaver ideas to solve the problem

Comment: Hey!  I have added my approach at an high level... do let me know your if its appropriate for your need or if you need a sample implementation.

Comment: Please tell me,  I'm online now

Comment: Hello kapoor,, are you online now?

Comment: Hello kapoor Hey!  "I have added my approach at an high level... do let me know your if its appropriate for your need or if you need a sample implementation. " unclear u don't understand what you want say sorry

Comment: Hello Ahmed, I have added a working sample to demonstrate my approach please have a look.

Comment: I will try and tell you results ,, thank you kapoor

Comment: Its working at my end, so may be the event handlers are not wired correctly - So there are 2 event handlers in my code 1> Initialise_Click : I have wired it to a button & it must be executed 1st.        2> dataGridView1_CellValueChanged : I have wired it to the CellValueChanged event of datagrid view, every time you change a cell's value and move to another cell this event fires up.     Can you please check if the event handlers are wired correctly

Comment: Here is a sample usage video as u needed its from the same code as i have given u - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4T_ObUhqCE&feature=youtu.be , please read the text too, there is some more elaboration. Do let me know if you need any help

Comment: Sure Ahmed! I'll try to redo it like a tutorial   My only intention for the previous video was to show the sequence of events from UI & how they change  the value. So you could check if the programe is working the same way at your end too.   Is it working the same way at your end now ? But can you please connect to me over a chat here... will it suit you fine to connect tomorrow at 1900 GMT ? please feel free to suggest another time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88619/discussion-between-kapoor-and-ahmed-tammaa).

Comment: Hello Ahmed! terribly sorry but I got occupied with few things at my end. here is the video i committed - https://youtu.be/XyXifsjPqb8   do let me know if you have any doubts