# How to filter richtextbox from bad words?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know how to automatically filter  `richtextbox`  from bad words in the text change event. I am developing a local chat software by using ip to create connection between the computers, but I need to filter it, e.g

```
Richtextbox.text = "oh s***";
```

`Richtextbox` will pop up a message box to alert the user and disable input for 5 seconds and then enable it again.

Comment: This being StackOverflow, what have you tried?

Comment: Edit your post to show your code, don't post it as a comment. That said, just compile a list of disallowed words and possible split your textbox on a space and see if it contains anything bad.

Comment: I am in mobile I can't :(

Comment: Could you edit it please :)

Comment: That condition will never evaluate to true. You're comparing a value to itself and then appending something to it-- changing the value. They'll never be the same.

Comment: @sab669 for that I need help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem! I guess, something like that:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...
  HashSet<String> badWords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "bad",
    "words",
  };

  Boolean result = YourRichTextBox
    .Lines
    .Any(line => Regex
       .Split(line, @"\W")
       .Any(word => badWords.Contains(word)));
```

Note that bad word can start from captital letter, capitalized etc. Another difficulty is that we have to detect `"BAD!"`, but not, say, `"baddy"`.

To *alert* the user just put the code into `TextChanged` event processing:

```
  private void YourRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RichTextBox YourRichTextBox = sender as RichTextBox;

    Boolean result = ... // See code above

    if (result) {
      MessageBox.Show("You must not be that rude!", Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: I got errors on this line ...Boolean result = YourRichTextBox
    .Lines
    .Any(line => line
      .Regex.Split(line, @"\w")
      .Any(word => badWords.Contains(word)));

Comment: @Ahmed Tammaa: add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to others *usings*

Comment: And where is the alert how to pop up the message box if the user use bad word ,, please upvote my question

Comment: ,, the error is still in didn't fix it sorry :( could you help?

Comment: Could you chat with me on stack chat room

Comment: note my autocomplete in C# suggest Any<> not support Any () ,, may be my eddition differ from yours ,, I use visual studio 2010 express!!

Comment: @Ahmed Tammaa: My copy of *2010 VS* (I've got Ultimate edition, however) compiled the code. Have got `using System.Linq;` within other `usings`?

Comment: never mind it works please check out my other question you are kind and nice helper thanks alot

Comment: @Ahmed Tammaa: It's OK, *challenging problems* are welcome!

Comment: You are my favourite , wait I will share links or you could checkout my profile , please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241708/how-to-make-formula-between-2-datagridview-in-c-sharp/32242257#32242257

Comment: The most difficult question, if it unclear ask I am online for 3 hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88498/discussion-between-ahmed-tammaa-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Answer (score 2):

Just had to implement this into my project, thought I'd share my code. I created a text file and stored this within the website, so it can be easily modified w/o having to re-compile or change web.config settings.

A good way to do this would be to do this on a button submit, since you're using a RTE. I'd say use ajax to check if it contains "bad words" prior to button submit so you don't have to do a postback, but it looks like you're using Win Forms, and this is MVC. But you can get the picture.

I used both English and Spanish "bad words" from this website, https://github.com/shutterstock/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words

The text file is placed in /Content folder (in my situation)

**Here's ajax if you can use (or if anybody else wants)**

```
$('#form-ID').on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function (e) {
    var badWords = '',
        str = $('#form-ID').find('textarea').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/YourAPI/CheckForBadWords?str=' + str,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function (data) {
            badWords = data.responseText;
        }
    });

    if (badWords != '') {
        console.log('oh no --- ' + badWords)
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }     
});
```

**Api Method - you could also put this into your Button submit event**

```
 [HttpPost] // <--- remove if not using Api
 public string CheckForBadWords(string str)
 {
     string badWords = string.Empty;
     var badWordsResult = Global.CheckForBadWords(str);
     if (badWordsResult.Length > 0)
     {
         badWords = string.Join(", ", badWordsResult);
     }

     return badWords;
 }
```

**Global.cs file**

```
public static class Global 
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a list of bad words found in the string based
        /// on spanish and english "bad words"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="str">the string to check</param>
        /// <returns>list of bad words found in string (if any)</returns>
        public static string[] CheckForBadWords(string str)
        {
            var badWords = GetBadWords();
            var badWordsCaught = new List<string>();

            if (badWords.Any(str.ToLower().Contains))
            {
                badWordsCaught = badWords.Where(x => str.Contains(x)).ToList();
            }

            return badWordsCaught.ToArray();
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a list of "bad words" from the text file. Words include
    /// both spanish and english
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>strings of bad words</returns>
    private static List<string> GetBadWords()
    {
        var badWords = new List<string>();
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}/Content/InvalidWords.txt", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            badWords = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
        }

        return badWords.ConvertAll(x => x.ToLower());
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Had to remove the querystring param from the api call b/c of URL character limits. Instead I just pass JSON string

```
var badWords = '',
    str = stringHERE;

$.ajax({
    url: '/YourApiController/CheckForBadWords',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ str: str }),
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    complete: function (data) {
        badWords = data.responseText;
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341393/how-to-extend-a-formula-to-2-datagridview?noredirect=1#comment52608588_32341393 could you answer it please

Comment: If you found it duplicated the the original question didn't get any answer please answer on of them :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this question's a bit broad, but you could probably do this using Linq:

```
List<string> badWords = new List<string> { "bad", "words", "here" };

string myString = "This string contains a bad word";

bool badWordInString = badWords.Any(myString.Contains);
```

`badWordInString` will be `true` if the `myString` contains any of the bad words from the list.

You could then use text replace to replace the offending word with a censored replacement.

The problem is that censoring in this fashion is that it doesn't account for things like the word *bad* being in the word *baddy*. You might want to allow *baddy*, but not *bad*, but since this is taking place in the text changed event handler, you'll never be able to type *baddy*.

A better solution would be to censor the text *after* it's sent, looking for word boundaries, trimming punctuation, ignoring casing and checking if entire words match.

Comment: I checking please wait results :)

Comment: Need more description where to post this code , in the richtextbox or creating linq query

Comment: You've edited the question since I answered, so I'll need to update it to filter. This will just let you know if a bad word is in the string.

Comment: @AhmedTammaa, have this code in textchanged event probably.

Comment: Yes, in the text changed event. Switch out `myString` with `Richtextbox.Text`

Comment: "You've edited the question since I answered, so I'll need to update it to filter. This will just let you know if a bad word is in the string" okay I am waiting

Comment: Counter example: "very BAD text HERE!" Your code doesn't find neither "BAD" no "HERE"

Comment: Another counter example is `"It's a good text, baddy"`. Your code will find `"bad"` in `"baddy"`

Comment: @Errseen your code is do nothing :( sorry but may be I do it wrong please edit and add description.

Comment: This is not necessarily that right way of solving the problem of censoring chat. It just finds strings within strings - I'd recommend Dmitry's answer, which use regex to find word boundaries. My answer doesn't *do nothing*!

Comment: `badWordInString` will be true if any of the bad words are within `myString`.

Answer (score 1):

1. put the banned words into db, when program start , cache it .

   - for testing , you hard code some words .
2. Since this is a string matching problem . I would suggest to use System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class, hope below link sample code would give you some help :
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx