# How to extend a formula to 2 datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I Would like to know how to make a calculated columns between 2 datagridviews 
if we are developing point of sale software.
and purchase order get a 2 product lets say "2 laptops" and the total is 5
so the total nust be updated to be 3. 
here is a note it could easly done if they are in the same datagrid views using this code

```
    Datacolumn column = new Datacolumn ();


column.Columnname = "Remaining";

Totaldataset.Tables[0].Columns.["Remaining"].Expression = "Total - Sold";
```

the question could it done if the column "Total" is in other Datagridview or any else column in other data grid view

Comment: Please if you do not know the answer please up vote my question

Comment: @M4N the both questions are mine but I didn't get any answer of both so what should I do ,, is this question is too hard for stack overflow?

Comment: You shouldn't post a question twice. If you didn't get any helpful answers, then it is most probably, because your question wasn't clear enough. Try to edit/improve your question in that case (add more information, ...). Hope this helps.

Comment: @M4N could you please edit from me please because I am not so good in English